# Is there a way to feed a column with a concated value from other two columns dynamically incrementing a int in a third column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a trigger function to feed a column with a value generated from a concatenation of two other columns with predetermined values. If the value already exists, I would increment a third column accordingly to the concatenated value.

EX:

```
column1 -> 'aaa' 
column2 -> 'bbb' 

concatenated value -> 'aaabbb'

column1 -> 'xxx'
column2 -> 'yyy'

concatenated value -> 'xxxyyy'`
```

If there's already rows with the value 'aaabbb' then the third column would be incremented as:

```
1 | aaabbb
2 | aaabbb
3 | aaabbb
1 | xxxyyy
2 | xxxyyy
```

Comment: So you want to insert a new row with the concatenated value and the count of values that match it?

Comment: Exactly, you description was perfect.

Comment: So after the insert `column1` would be `'aaabbb'`, `column2` would be `NULL` and `column3` is the count of matching values? Or are both `column1` and `column2` the concatenated value?

Comment: The concacted value from `column1` and `column2` would be inserted in an another column and would have the column for count the concat values. In the end would be four columns.

Comment: As a rule of thumb for relational database: do not store data that can easily be derived from existing values. Create a view that returns that information and forget about storing the data redudantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this code, its work to only insert. But you can duplicate trigger and change to update too.

```
create table test ( column1 varchar, column2 varchar, column3 varchar);

CREATE TRIGGER t_before_test
  BEFORE insert 
  ON test

FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE fnt_test();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnt_test()
  RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
declare
    v_count int := 0;
BEGIN
    select 1 into v_count from test where column1 = NEW.column1 and column2 = NEW.column2;
    if ( NEW.column1 is not null and NEW.column2 is not null and v_count > 0) then
        NEW.column3 := NEW.column1 || NEW.column2;
    end if;

 RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;

insert into test ( column1, column2 ) values ( '1', '2');

select * from test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to save concatenated value. This one does not save it, but you can of course save concatenated value into `new.concatenated_column`:

```
create function f_test ()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    new.column3 := (
        select coalesce(max(t.column3) + 1, 1)
        from test as t
        where t.column1 || t.column2 = new.column1 || new.column2
    );

    return new;
end;    
$$

create trigger tr_test
before insert
on test
for each row execute procedure f_test();
```

[`db<>fiddle demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5edca204e9dc7a33f627ca7eb9246a76)